# How to update Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE version to my project?

Tags: spring-mvc

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping

How can I update Spring 4.1.6 RELEASE version to my project?

```
 @Controller
 public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/welcome/{countryName}/{userName}") 
  public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable Map < String, String > pathVars) {
  String name = pathVars.get("userName");
  String country = pathVars.get("countryName");
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
  modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Hello " + name + "You are from" + country);
  return modelAndView;
 }
```

This is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.learningspringmvc.controller"></context:component-scan>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
       <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>
        </bean>
        </beans>
```

Comment: You have update the maven pom.xml file with the desired spring version. Although I doubt this will solve your missing path variable issue.

Comment: paste your controller code, its where you have the problem not in your spring version

Comment: please post full working example demo-ing your problem

Comment: i am not using maven and pom.xml

Comment: @SivakumarMunusamy what are you using in place of Maven?

Comment: And why? Manual dependency management is generally a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver.html) which you're trying to use is present in Spring 4.1.6 RELEASE, so your code should work.

You have probably not enabled Spring Web MVC.

You either need to include `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your xml config, or use the [`@EnableWebMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html).

Comment: I enabled Spring Web MVC

Comment: What is the Spring version you're running - is it 4.1.6 RELEASE? How do you handle dependency management, if you're not using Maven?

Comment: How can i check which spring version running my application?

Comment: If you are running a Spring application, Spring jars should be on the class path - which means you should be able to locate those jars on the file system - normally they have the version in the name. You can also check this from your IDE - depends on what you're using - normally those jar are listed under Libraries. Looking at your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml you're probably running Spring 3.2

Comment: #hovanessyan Thank you so much, you save me...It's working fine.

Comment: @SivakumarMunusamy you can accept the answer if you find it helpful. Thanks